# Kentico - How to know if/when the whole website was down

Tags: kentico

Is there a way to know when/if the whole website was down? And even better, the reason that it was down. I don't have access to the servers, only have access to Kentico admin with global admin privileges. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Down as in the user trying to visit the site is getting a 503 Error?

If it goes down because of an error in Kentico, you would be able to check the event log, but if it is a server error you would need to check the server event logs.

There are a bunch of services online that will notify you when your site isn't responding like [Uptimer Robot](https://uptimerobot.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the Uptimer Robot link.

Answer (score 2):

One of the options is integrate your Kentico App with Azure Application Insights.

You can configure

- .Net Performance monitoring via usage analytics (server
  resources like http response time)
- Status monitor to diagnose IIS
  issues on live running web sites (without re-deploying)
- Usage
  analytics for pages of the website (client side like Google
  Analytics)
- Automated stress testing System availability and health
  monitoring (think uptime / downtime tracking)
- Crash reporting for
  apps and devices

http://www.mcbeev.com/Blog/April-2016/Application-Insights-for-Kentico